# Animate navigation header opacity while scrolling in ScrollView in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-reanimated

I need your help for animation in React native.
In my screen, I want to change opacity of navigation header 0 to 1 when I scroll up.

Here is code in [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@freewebwithme777/726ceb)

I declare animated value in HomeScreen like this.

**In Homescreen.js**

```
export const translationY = new Value(0)
```

Why I am using 'export' is to use animated value in navigation header

**In HomeStackNavigator.js file**

```
import {translationY} from './HomeScreen';

const forFade = () => {
  const opacity = interpolate(translationY, {
    inputRange: [
      0,
      BUTTON_CONTAINER_HEIGHT - 100,
      height - getStatusBarHeight(),
    ],
    outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
    extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });
  return {
    backgroundStyle: {opacity},
  };
};

export function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Intro" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen name="Intro" component={IntroScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerStyleInterpolator: forFade,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The other animatio in HomeScreen works. But animation doesn't work in navigation header.
How can I do this? What am I missing?
Is it problem exporting animated value(translationY)?